# How do I determine what hostnames do not resolve to an IP address?

Tags: bash, shell, hostname

I'm using bash shell on Mac 10.9.1.  Given a file of hostnames, which might ocntain entries like

```
dave.mydomain.com
dave2.otherdomain.com
somethingelse.whatever.com
```

How can I determine which of the host names in the file does not resolve to an IP address?

Comment: You could try pinging them.  That normally returns a resolved IP.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a scriptable way -- something other than pinging each entry in the file individually.

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting.  Put it into a bash script.  I don't know how you expect to test them if not individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read each hostname from the file, perform a DNS lookup of the hostname, and check the response:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read hstnm
do
  if ! host ${hstnm} > /dev/null
  then
    echo "No ip for ${hstnm}"
  fi
done < hostnames.txt
```

I used the [`host`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_%28Unix%29) utility in this example, but you could also use [`dig`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28command%29) (piped into `grep -q` for "NXDOMAIN", for example), or [`nslookup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup).

---

`dig` + `grep` example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read hstnm
do 
  if dig ${hstnm} | grep -q 'NXDOMAIN'
  then 
    echo "no ip for ${hstnm}"
  fi
done < hostnames.txt
```

Comment: it should be noted that this does not resolve entries in `/etc/hosts`.